# What vectors am I allowed to multiply a matrix by when calculating it's norm?

Tags: matrices, vectors, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

So I'm learning about matrix norms and I think I understand what they represent, but I'm confused with something...

> To solve this problem, consider the effect that matrix $A$ has on the simplest unit vectors, $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$: \begin{align} \begin{bmatrix}1 & -3 \\ 2 & 8\end{bmatrix} \cdot \color{red}{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}} &= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}  & \left\| \begin{bmatrix}1 \\2 \end{bmatrix}\right\|_1 &= |1|+|2| = 3 \\ 
> \begin{bmatrix}1 & -3 \\ 2 & 8\end{bmatrix} \cdot \color{red}{\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}} &= \begin{bmatrix}-3 \\ 8\end{bmatrix}  & \left\| \begin{bmatrix}-3 \\8 \end{bmatrix}\right\|_1 &= |{-}3|+|8| = 11
> \end{align}

As you can see, the matrix is multiplied by two vectors, first by [1;0] and then by [0,1], in order to find it's norm

-Can I multiply it with [1;1] and see if it produces a "better" result?

Because later on in an example it multiplies a 2x3 matrix by [1;1;1] vector so... there can be all ones? or not?

Comment: Your link isn't working for me.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKwVz.png try this

Comment: Which matrix norm are you talking about? Please provide the definition.

Comment: From the figure it is not clear what is the problem.Do you want to find the matrix norm induced by the vector $1-$norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: If I want to determine they one-norm, what vectors am I allowed to try to amplify? Stupid example- instead of [1;0], can I multiply by [500;500]?

Comment: @M.Wother the definition is pretty clear. If you state it, there no room for doubt...

Comment: Well what is the definition? I can't find it anywhere, that's the problem I think

Comment: There is a Wikipedia article called matrix norm ...

Comment: Most of the induced norms are hard to calculate. The three that are always used are the 2-norm, the 1-norm, and the $\infty$-norm. I'm afraid they were just showing you sample vectors for you to get a feeling about this. You need to consider ***all*** vectors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* like you're talking about the [operator matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm).

This can be defined as:
$$
||A||_p = \sup_{v\,:\,||v||_p\ne 0} \frac{||Av||_p}{||v||_p}
$$
Or equivalently as:
$$
||A||_p = \sup_{v\,:\,||v||_p = 1} ||Av||_p
$$
which I tend to prefer.

So, in this case, **yes**, you not only *should* consider other vectors, you *have to* do so. The norm is defined to take the *maximum over all possible unit vectors*.
This means that such norms can be hard to directly calculate from its definition.

However, for some cases, there are easier shortcuts. For instance, when $p=1$, one can use:
$$
||A||_1 = \max_j \sum_i |a_{ij}|
$$
or when $p=\infty$, it is
$$
||A||_\infty = \max_i \sum_j |a_{ij}|
$$
or when $p=2$, one can compute
$$
||A||_2 = \max_i\sigma_i(A) = \max_i\sqrt{\lambda_i(A^TA)}
$$
where $\sigma_j(M)$ and $\lambda_j(M)$ are the singular values and eigenvalues of $M$.